# What beings are included in Thanos' culling?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

I've seen a few threads on whether or not Thanos would have been able to defeat Dormammu in single combat. It seems to be mostly speculation, but it got me thinking.

Did Dormammu have a 50/50 chance of also

> perishing with Thanos' snap? Or is he a being outside the scope of that is defined as "life"?

Also, what about the rest of the creatures on Earth?

> Were half the cats and dogs wiped out too? What about insects?

In *Avengers: Infinity War* we only really got to see

> humans fall victim to the snap, but Thanos explicitly said "half of all life", and it didn't seem to be species-specific.

More importantly, if Thanos killed

> half of all animals on Earth,

that would go a long way towards critically messing up the planet's entire ecosystem. Possibly beyond repair.

Comment: As I understand it, Dormammu is a being of (or an expression of) a parallel universe. Each universe has their own infinity gems, which do not work in other dimensions. Dormammu was affected by the Time gem because he was extended into our dimension, and that part was caught in the loop. So, no, he would be unaffected by Thanos.

Comment: IMO, this should not be a dupe, or at least the dupe target should be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

## All Life

> In an interview with Birth Movies Death, Marvel Studios CEO Kevin Feige confirmed that it wasn't just people that died with that finger snapping. When asked about plants and animals, Feige confirmed that **half of the plants and animals of the world are now gone**, too. He said, "Yes! Yes. All life."
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://screenrant.com/infinity-war-thanos-snap-animals-plants-killed/)</sup>

Now we know that this extends to the 616 spacial universe but whether it extends to other "realms/universes/dimensions", such as that of Dormammu isn't clear but it seems unlikely.

As to whether Thanos *could* have been included in the snap...Joe Russo said...

> You can ask if he allowed himself to be apart of that random process. He does have a very interesting look on his face. When we come back to him after the snap before he disappears, a look of surprise.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://io9.gizmodo.com/joe-russo-gave-the-infinity-war-answers-youve-been-wait-1825776831)</sup>

...which can be interpreted both ways depending on your viewpoint.

See also this [**M&TV Q&A**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88478/was-thanos-really-committed-or-just-a-hypocrite)

Comment: That certainly is very sensible. But they didn't bother to show the trees in Wakanda vanishing, did they?

Comment: No..but that's probably more a question of not confusing the audience rather than absolute accuracy.